# JLabel can't keep up with mouse

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, mouseevent

I have a small program, that creates a something, that could be considered a joystick. Everything works, but there is a glitch, I can't work out how to fix. If mouse moves too fast, the `JLabel` that I'm dragging around, sticks, as mouse has moved outside of the drawn box. I could increase the size of `Jlabel`, but then the "O" is offset too much from mouse. (I'd rather even decrease the size, but with this implementation, maximum mouse speed is too low).
Any ideas how to fix this?

This is the whole code, btw, anyone can go ahead and compile, to see what is the problem exactly, when mouse moves too fast.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MainClass implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
int labelSize = 20;
int screenOffsetX = 58;
int screenOffsetY = 130;
JFrame frame;
JLabel xAxis;
JLabel move;
JLabel drag;
JLabel yAxis;
JLabel xAxisDrag;
JLabel yAxisDrag;
JLabel radio;
JLayeredPane panel;
Robot rob;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new MainClass();
}
public MainClass()
{   
    frame = new JFrame("app");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setBounds(20, 20, 400, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    move = new JLabel("Movement");
    move.setBounds(150, 0, 100, 15);
    frame.add(move);

    xAxis = new JLabel("X");
    xAxis.setBounds(100, 20, 50, 15);
    frame.add(xAxis);

    yAxis = new JLabel("Y");
    yAxis.setBounds(200, 20, 50, 15);
    frame.add(yAxis);

    drag = new JLabel("Dragging");
    drag.setBounds(150, 40, 100, 15);
    frame.add(drag);

    xAxisDrag = new JLabel("X");
    xAxisDrag.setBounds(100, 60, 50, 15);
    frame.add(xAxisDrag);

    yAxisDrag = new JLabel("Y");
    yAxisDrag.setBounds(200, 60, 50, 15);
    frame.add(yAxisDrag);

    radio = new JLabel("O");
    radio.setBounds(0, 0, labelSize, labelSize);
    radio.setOpaque(false);
    radio.setEnabled(false);
    panel = new JLayeredPane();
    panel.setBounds(50, 100, 257, 257);
    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.setBackground(new Color((float)1.0,(float)1.0,(float)1.0));
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    panel.add(radio);
    radio.setLocation(128, 128);
    frame.add(panel);
    panel.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    panel.addMouseListener(this);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
{
    if(!(e.getPoint().x<0 || e.getPoint().y<0 || e.getPoint().x>257 || e.getPoint().y>257))
    {   
        xAxis.setText("X: "+((e.getPoint().x/4)-32));
        yAxis.setText("Y: "+((e.getPoint().y/4)-32));
    }
    if(e.getPoint().x<0 || e.getPoint().y<0 || e.getPoint().x>257 || e.getPoint().y>257)
    {   //Neļauj iziet ārpus paneļa;
        try
        {
            rob = new Robot();
            if(e.getPoint().x<0)
                rob.mouseMove((screenOffsetX+frame.getX()), (e.getPoint().y+screenOffsetY+frame.getY()));
            if(e.getPoint().y<0)
                rob.mouseMove((e.getPoint().x+screenOffsetX+frame.getX()), (screenOffsetY+frame.getY()));
            if(e.getPoint().x>257)
                rob.mouseMove((257+screenOffsetX+frame.getX()), (e.getPoint().y+screenOffsetY+frame.getY()));
            if(e.getPoint().y>257)
                rob.mouseMove((e.getPoint().x+screenOffsetX+frame.getX()), (257+screenOffsetY+frame.getY()));
        }
        catch (AWTException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(     (e.getPoint().x>=radio.getX() && e.getPoint().x<=radio.getX()+labelSize) && 
            (e.getPoint().y>=radio.getY() && e.getPoint().y<=radio.getY()+labelSize)
            )
    {   //Ja kursors ir uz JLabel, tad pārvieto;
        xAxisDrag.setText("X: "+((e.getPoint().x/4)-32));
        yAxisDrag.setText("Y: "+((e.getPoint().y/4)-32));
        radio.setBounds(e.getPoint().x-(labelSize/2), e.getPoint().y-(labelSize/2), labelSize, labelSize);
    }
}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
{
    xAxis.setText("X: "+((e.getPoint().x/4)-32));
    yAxis.setText("Y: "+((e.getPoint().y/4)-32));
}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    radio.setLocation(124, 124);
    xAxisDrag.setText("X: "+0);
    yAxisDrag.setText("Y: "+0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
     if(     (e.getPoint().x>=radio.getX() && e.getPoint().x<=radio.getX()+labelSize) && 
        (e.getPoint().y>=radio.getY() && e.getPoint().y<=radio.getY()+labelSize)
        )
{   //Ja kursors ir uz JLabel, tad pārvieto;
    xAxisDrag.setText("X: "+((e.getPoint().x/4)-32));
    yAxisDrag.setText("Y: "+((e.getPoint().y/4)-32));
    radio.setBounds(e.getPoint().x-(labelSize/2), e.getPoint().y-(labelSize/2), labelSize, labelSize);
}
```

by:

```
  if(      (e.getPoint().x>=radio.getX() && e.getPoint().x<=radio.getX()+labelSize) && 
        (e.getPoint().y>=radio.getY() && e.getPoint().y<=radio.getY()+labelSize)
        )
{
    //Has the mouse been clicked inside the radio before grabbing started ?
    if(grab==0)  //if it is the first iteration of the function mousedragged
        grab=2;  //proceed to "grab"
}

if(grab==2 &&   (e.getPoint().x>=0 && e.getPoint().x<panel.getWidth()) && 
        (e.getPoint().y>=0 && e.getPoint().y<panel.getHeight())
        )
{   //Ja kursors ir uz JLabel, tad pārvieto;
    System.out.println(radio.getX()+" "+radio.getY());
    xAxisDrag.setText("X: "+((e.getPoint().x/4)-32));
    yAxisDrag.setText("Y: "+((e.getPoint().y/4)-32));
    radio.setBounds(e.getPoint().x-(labelSize/2), e.getPoint().y-(labelSize/2), labelSize, labelSize);

}
if(grab!=2)  // if grabbing is not started
   grab=1; // first iteration is over
```

Update MouseReleased function to:

```
        @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        //this a new line
        //grabbing is over
        grab=0;  // go back to idle state
        radio.setLocation(124, 124);
        xAxisDrag.setText("X: "+0);
        yAxisDrag.setText("Y: "+0);
    }
```

Finally , add a new field called grab to your class MainClass:

```
  private int grab=0;  //idle state
```

The meaning of grab:
1. grab=0 => It is the first time that the function MouseDragged is executed and "grabbing" is not started yet. In fact when you drag the mouse this function is iterated like an infinite loop until you release the mouse. So it is important to know when it has started.
2. grab=1 => Iteration has started but there is no "grabbing"
3. grab=2 => "grabbing" has started. You can notice the condition grab==0 before the affectation. In fact I tried to avoid the case when the mouse is dragged from somewhere else and goes through "radio" and then the radio is "grabbed". That's why I checked that it is the first iteration. In this case we have grab=1 => the radio is not grabbed

Comment: It is supposed to be like that. If I use your suggestion, `radio` moves to any point inside panel, when mouse is clicked. It needs to be like I "grab" the `radio`, and move it around.

Comment: @user3665674 please vote it as an answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: Indeed it worked, thank you. For now I simply copied it in, now I will go through the code again, to make sure I understand exactly why it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: I would if I could, a bit too little "reputation".